# Parse SQL schema file with regex (python)

Tags: python, regex

I've tried to find a suitable answer here, but I'm struggling.

I have a file

```
create table "user".tablename 
  (
    columna char(4) not null ,
    columnb varchar(32),
    columnc varchar(16),
    updated datetime year to second 
        default current year to second not null ,
    edited_by varchar(18,10) 
        default current_user not null 
  );

create unique index "user".xpktablename on "user".tablename 
    (columna) using btree ;
alter table "user".tablename add constraint primary key 
    (columna) constraint "user".xpktablename  ;
```

now I've written the python to figure out where it is in the file (creating a table, trigger, index etc). But, I can't figure out how to pull out the columns.

Essentially, what I'm doing is trying to build SQLAlchemy classes from schema dumps:

So, this would become:

```
class tablename(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tablename'

    columna = Column(String, primary_key = True)
    columnb = Column(String, nullable = True)
    columnc = Column(String, nullable = True)
    updated = Column(DateTime, nullable = False)
    edited_by = Column(String, nullable = False) 

    Index.....
```

As above, I don't care about defaults, for now - that is another complexity worthy of a separate question.

What I can't get is analysing the column line with the parenthesis: varchar(xxx)

I was looking for ([datetime year to second|integer|smallint]), but I don't know how to do a subregex inside the literal bracket that looks for the (xxx) ?

I'm guessing this is not overly complex, I just don't understand regex well enough.

Any help or push in the right direction would be appreciated.

If it helps, this is what I have at the moment that I'm trying to work on:

```
column = re.search("^    ([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,})\s([serial|integer|smallint|datetime year to second|date])")
```

Comment: I think that trying to parse arbitrary SQL using regular expressions is going to hurt. A lot.  SQLAlchemy already has an [introspection mechanism](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/reflection.html) that will get you SQLAlchemy classes from a database.

Comment: @larsks unfortunately there is no direct DB access, only via schema dump files. The dumps are very consistent in terms of format and layout, just the datatypes are potentially random

Comment: So, I've decided trying to be too smart with regex was a mistake. Once I took a step back I was able to see a series of string replacements, then more simple regular expression checks with lookarounds sorted out the issue. --- I will post the full code for  this once it's done and tested as I believe there are some who would like this.